# saving files labeled with increasing number

Tags: python

Very similar questions out already but I haven't been able to find one that really matches what I have going on.

This is a facial recognition app with about 200 lines of code so I will just post the part that is relevant.

The app does face recognition and then displays a the target photo next to the best matched mugshot. In case of false positives it also shows a list of the best 5 matches.

I would like for the images in this list to also be saved as mug1.jpg, mug2.jpg etc.

Relevant piece of code:

```
    # create new array by removing the identified best match 
    # new_array = np.absolute(face_distances-best_match_index)
    # set distance between known faces and target face. The lower the distance between them the lower the match. Higher dist = more error.
        if  face_distances[best_match_index] < 0.60:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
            resulttolog = ("Match found within default tolerance level. " + "\n" "Best match: " + name + "\n")
            log(resulttolog) #logging result

            #save and display mugshot of best match
            mugshot = cv2.imread(os.getcwd() + "/datasets/" + name + ".jpg")
            mugshotresized = cv2.resize(mugshot, (500, 500), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
            cv2.imwrite(os.getcwd() + "/mugshot.jpg", mugshotresized)                

        #listing other closest maches
        best_5_matches = n_known_face_names[top_3_matches]
        matchestolist =  list(best_5_matches)
        log("Top matches in order:")

        #sort list by number
        for index, mugshot in enumerate(matchestolist, 1):
            log("{}. {}".format(index, mugshot)) #log the numbered list
            
        #save up relevant matches
        for filename in matchestolist:
            path = (os.getcwd() + "/datasets/")
            file = (path + filename + ".jpg")
            img = cv2.imread(file)
            i = 0
            cv2.imwrite(filename + "mug{}.jpg".format(i), img)
            i +=1
```

At the bottom here, the images are getting saved but they are getting saved with their original filename with 'mug0' appended on each filename.. not sure how to fix this.

I have tried the %s formatting variant but it does the same thing. Error must be somewhere else.

Comment: You have `i = 0` just before the line where you save the images, so of course the filename has a zero inserted into it via `.format()`.  Move the initialization of that variable outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. that fixed it. Simple enough but for those of us that kinda suck at this a simple thing can stump you sometimes

Answer (score -1):

Corrected code using the above comment:

```
            i = 0
        for filename in matchestolist:
            path = (os.getcwd() + "/datasets/")
            file = (path + filename + ".jpg")
            img = cv2.imread(file)
            cv2.imwrite("mug{}.jpg".format(i), img)
            i +=1
```